# How to use anigo-anime-api with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

i want to use the anigo-anime-api

https://www.npmjs.com/package/anigo-anime-api

https://github.com/anigo-animeapi/anigo-anime-api

integrate it and use the API within angular.

I've followed the documentation, used the require keyword but it doesn't seem to be working.

I tried utilizing the API in a different node.js application and it works fine. Is there a way to use this npm package inside of angular rather than a different node.js application.

Comment: Hello, as explained in the documentation, that's intended for NodeJS projects, so on backend side. You'd need to create an API in your NodeJS application to communicate with it on Angular side.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon Isnt there any work arounds that allows to directly use the package within angular ?

Comment: If it's meant to scrape content as explained by the documentation, you cannot use it directly on Angular side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GérômeGrignon